Tensorflow Lite for Microcontrollers Build for ARMCortex-M4
I want to build tensorflow lite for microcontrollers to be able to use it as library for my ARMCortex-M4 based board. Overall purpose for my application is to train a model in tensorflow and convert it to C array. Then, I want to use this model from C array in my code by using TFLite Micro APIs.
I read TFLite Microcontrollers documentation. However, it seems too complex. I would really appreciate if there is a step by step documentation.
I tried to build the TFLite for Microcontrollers with Bazel. For Windows I couldn't generate a library for ARMCortex-M4. I get the library for Linux but it didn't work.
